# How do I get this script to check for keywords in embedded links instead of just messages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

could someone please help me get the formatting changed for this so it can work with embedded links and open them in my default browser.  I've attached a pic of how the links how in discord channel.

any help would be grateful. discord.py seems to be broken from today so need to change to discord.js

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if (config.channelIds && config.channelIds.length > 0 && !config.channelIds.includes(message.channel.id)) return;

  const urls = new Set(matchUrls(message.content));
  if (urls.length == 0) return;

  urls.forEach(async url => {
    if (
      config.keywords.some(keyword =>
        url.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
      ) &&
      !config.negativeKeywords.some(
        keyword => keyword && url.toLowerCase().includes(keyword.toLowerCase())
      )
    ) {
      logger.info(`Opening ${url}`);
      open(url);
    } else {
      logger.info(`${url} not in keywords or is in negative keywords`);
    }
  });
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

[image: embedded messages example]

Comment: looking to detect keywords in "Link" value

Comment: Will all of the embeds be in this exact format? Ex. It will always have **Product URL** and then after that it'll have a link in there?